# Difference between async post request and form post

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, asynchronous

I made a website in django 1.7.

First I tried sending asynchronous post request with the help of jquery -

```
$.post('http://mywebsite.com/info',{params: params})
        .done(function(data)
        {
            if(data.data != 'OK')
                alert('Something Went Wrong');
            else
            {
                alert('OK');

            }
        })
```

It worked fine on desktop but did not worked at all in my mobile.

I thought may be it was due to speed of net connection.

Then I tried posting HTML form and reloading the page-

```
<form id="list-form" method="post" class="hide">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <my params >
    </form>
```

And it worked fine on both desktop and mobile.

So what is the difference in doing the above two methods. I guessed that asynchronous post request must be faster than posting a form and also reloading the page but it failed in mobiles.

Any suggestions are welcome.

And if there is anything else that I can do to avoid reloading the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In theory, there is no difference. However, saying 'it didn't work' is very vague. Was the request not made? Did it fail? Did it contain the same data? My guess would be that the `params` variable in your `$.post` had issues.

Comment: No, because same thing was working good on desktop, it was just in mobiles where I don't know what happened but no response came.

Comment: No response came back, maybe because no request was made, or a wrong request.

Comment: But response came in desktop and did not come in mobile for the same peice of code.

Comment: Maybe you can provide us browser logs? Try to use chome devtools or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference that "async post request" is AJAX-request, so it has additional header "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest".

But in normal situation it should not lead to troubles you experienced.